# Dynamic Form Modification

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic form with two dynamic form elements.

I've followed the examples from https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

I can create a form which shows the new form element Position after selecting and submitting Sport.

However lets say after choosing a Position and submitting they have to choose a colour, how would you do this?

I've tried adding a new event listener for position but it never gets called.

```
         $builder->get('position')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $position = $event->getForm()->getData();
                dump($position);

                $event->getForm()->add('colour', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => Colour::class,
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'choices' => ['red','green','blue'],
                ]);

            }
        );
```

For example in this test data, the sport is football the position is striker and the  colours allowed are Red and Green, for the position goalie the colours might be Yellow and Black.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add the `colour` field to the wrong form.
With `$event->getForm()` you are retrieving the "position" form, not the main form which is the one you want to modify.

I've commented your code to explain this better.

```php
/* Here you're correctly registering an event listener to the "position" field, POST_SUBMIT event */
$builder->get('position')->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
        // $event->getForm() here will return the "position" field form
        $position = $event->getForm()->getData();
        dump($position);

        // In the documentation example here the $formModifier closure is used
        // with $event->getForm()->getParent() as first argument

        // What you missed here is the getParent() call
        $event->getForm()
            ->getParent() // <- This will return the main form, the one you built with $builder
            ->add('colour', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Colour::class,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => ['red','green','blue'],
            ]);
    }
);
```

What you missed in your event listener is a `getParent()` call just before the `add` call.

Comment: I tried something similar to that but when you have `$builder->get('position')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,...` and `$builder->get('sport')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,...` only sport gets called.

Comment: Without knowing what you’re doing in the `sport` event listener it’s impossible to tell what’s wrong. I can only suppose that you’re overwriting the `position` form field with a new one, thus removing the old field with the listener attached.

Comment: The code I am testing with is a copy and paste from the symfony doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms the `get('sport')` listener is identical code to that.

Comment: As I thought, the `$form->add('position', …` in the `formModifier` closure removes the field you are getting from the builder and add a new field with no listener attached